# FFMPEG install on Amazon Cloud9 IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am attempting to install FFMPEG on my cloud9 instance.  Everything seems to be going peachy until I receive the following:

```
configure: checking for guile 3.0
configure: found guile 3.0
checking for guile-3.0... no
checking for guile3.0... no
checking for guile-3... no
checking for guile3... no
checking for guile... /home/ubuntu/.linuxbrew/opt/guile@2/bin/guile
configure: error: found development files for Guile 3.0, but 
/home/ubuntu/.linuxbrew/opt/guile@2/bin/guile has effective version 2.2
```

I am SUPER ubuntu newb but it seems there is some baked-in version conflict that is stopping this process?